# Consul - Alert if drive is full

Tags: consul

In the demo of consul, there are checks for disk utilization and memory utilization. [image]

http://demo.consul.io/ui/#/ams2/nodes/ams2-server-1

How could you write a configuration to do what the demo shows? Warning at 10% and critical erros at 5% ?

Here is what I am trying

```
{
  "check": {
     "name": "Disk Util",
     "script": "disk_util=$(df -k | grep '/dev/sda1' | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' ) | if [ $disk_util >  90 ] ; then echo 'Disk /dev/sda above 90% full' && exit 1; elif [ $disk_util > 80 ] ; then echo 'Disk /dev/sda above 80%' && exit 3;  else exit 0; fi",
     "interval": "2m"
     }
}
```

Here is the same script, but more human readable

```
disk_util=$(df -k | grep '/dev/sda1' | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' ) | 
if [ $disk_util >  90 ] 
 then echo 'Disk /dev/sda above 90% full' && exit 1
elif [ $disk_util > 80 ] 
 then echo 'Disk /dev/sda above 80%' && exit 3
else exit 0; fi
```

It seems like the check is working, but it doesn't print out any text. How can I verify this is working, and print output?

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to figure out use cases for consul, myself. Looking to see what others are doing with it outside of simple service discovery, or how to make service discovery more robust. I wonder why your question has just been downvoted? Perhaps because this is a question better suited for ServerFault? Regardless, I, too, would like to know 1) if this is a valid approach and 2) why output isn't shown. Hmph.

Comment: It is more likely to work if you invoke a shell script from the filesystem instead of trying to encapsulate it all inside the JSON "check" structure. Because the `exit` commands work better that way. P.S. New URL: https://demo.consul.io/ui/#/ams2/nodes/consul-server-ams2-1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The output that you are seeing is produced by Nagios plugin check_disk (https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/doc/man/check_disk.html)
2. The "Output" field gets populated by stdout of the check. Your check runs cleanly and produces no output. So you see nothing.
3. To add some notes just add a "notes" field in the check definition as outlined in the documentation: https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/checks.html

Your check json file would look something like this:

```
{
  "check": {
    "name": "disks",
    "notes": "Critical 5%, warning 10% free",
    "script": "/path/to/check_disk -w 10% -c 5%",
    "interval": "2m"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Exit code for your warning state should be 1, for critical, 2 or higher. (See "Check Scripts" at https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/checks.html), so you likely want to swap your exit lines.

Your 'OK' state (disk use < 80%) does not give any output, which is most likely why you see blank output.

I second the notion of using nagios plugins rather than rolling your own.  Many OSes will have a nagios-plugins package(s) that are a yum/apt install away.

Answer (score 0):

Health checks rely on the exit code of the check. To test if the health checks are being read by the Consul server you could write a script that always exits with a 1, and then you will see the health check as failed. Then replace it with a script that always returns 0 and you should see the health check as passed.

If you want to return text to the ui, add an [output](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/issues/157) field to the json.

Answer (score 0):

It seem consul analyse `stdout` only and not `stderr`. I have tested with redirect ( **`2>&1`** ) in service check file configuration. That seem work !

**JSON config**

```
{
  "check": {
    "name": "disks",
    "notes": "Critical 5%, warning 10% free",
    "script": "/path/to/check_disk -w 10% -c 5% 2>&1",
    "interval": "2m"
  }
}
```

**Output result**

[image]